# A destructor Shall OR shall not be declared with a pointer ? in C++

Tags: c++, destructor, declaration, c++11

In C++0x -n3290 Draft : they added  in section :Destructors : 12.4/2nd point last line

```
          **A destructor shall not be declared with a ref-qualifier.**
```

In c++03 Draft .... they didn't mention this point in destructors ?

my question is whether

```
   *~S() ;   //this declaration is allowed or not according to the Standard's
   //**~S(); ***~S() ; etc...........
```

this type of declaration is allowed ? 
No where in the Draft he described about this ...Declaration?

In GCC 4.6.0,Sun/Oracle C++12.0 , --->this declaration is allowed 
int Comeau C/C++ -->not allowed

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have misunderstood what *ref-qualifier* means in the new standard. In the same way that you can provide a `const` qualifier to any member function in C++03, you can also add a *ref-qualifier* to a member function in C++0x. That modifier will affect the type of the implicit `this` argument to the function:

```
struct test {
   void f() const &&;  // implicit "this" in "f" is of type "test const &&"
};
```

In the same way that a destructor cannot be `static`, or `const`, or `const volatile` in C++03, it cannot take a *ref-qualifier* (`&` or `&&`) in C++0x. Of course this bit was not present in the former standard.

Comment: @ DAvid :oh ... but in terms of a declaration of an destructor ..they only said abut ~ operator ..but no where they said about ...such declaration is allowed ,not allowed etc ... like *~A(),&~A() , etc

Comment: @user751747: The grammar states that the *ref-qualifier* is appended to functions on the far right (after the *cv-qualifiers*), and that means that the sentence refers to: `~A() &;` or `~A() &&;`, and defines both of them as invalid. `&~A();` and `*~A();` are invalid because they do not match the *grammar*, there is no need to provide additional descriptions on everything that should not compile. For example, nowhere in the standard it says that `a][+=/a` is incorrect, it only states what constructs are correct and that one does not match any of them.

Comment: @David I think that's incorrect `*~A()` aswell as `&~A()` matches the grammar. There should be some rule that make them invalid. I haven't checked for that rule yet...

Comment: @litb: Where in the grammar is that allowed? I have started from *member-specification* (assuming that the context on which the destructor was being declared is a member declarator), and I haven't found any place where the grammar allows a *member-specification* to start with a `*`. How can you get to that?

Comment: @David `*` is a `ptr-operator` and is part of `declarator` (`member-declarator`). Think of `int *a;` without the `int`.

Comment: @litb: I have spent a while (during the build times) to go over the grammar, and I have not seen anything to refute that claim, but I am just wondering what sense does that make, as the *declarator* in the grammar is basically stating that `* a;` is a valid member declaration (according to grammar only), which seems to indicate that there is a problem with the grammar being too flexible in that context.

Comment: @David there is a syntax constraint that states that the decl-specifier-seq may only be omitted for a member-declaration that declares a constructor, destructor or conversion function. A `*a` is none of those, which means that `*a` is invalid.

Answer (score 10):

That doesn't look like it would ever be a legal function declaration of any kind, much less for a destructor. I'm not positive what that part of the standard is talking about, but I have a guess.

I suspect there is a qualifier saying that your function is being called on an rvalue reference.  Something like this:

```
class A {
 public:
   void IAmAnRValue() &&;
};
```

I think the language in the standard is saying that this qualifier is not allowed on a destructor, much like having a trailing `const` would also be illegal.

And, on further investigation, my certainty of  the correctness of my surmise goes up considerably.  Here is the justification:

- [Extending Move Semantics to `*this`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2439.htm).

There it clearly states that functions may now have a 'ref-qualifier' after the 'cv-qualifer'. This means that a function declaration may now be followed by `const &` or `const volatile &&` instead of just `const`. And the term used (ref-qualifier) is the same as the term used in the little bit of the standard you're quoting. And it makes sense for destructors to not be able to have one.

Answer (score 1):

The rule you are looking for is stated in the same paragraph, 12.4p2

> A destructor takes no parameters, and no return type can be specified for it (not even void).

The phrase "no return type can be specified for it" also forbids "*", which is not immediately clear but can be seen by comparison with 12.3.2p1 (compare with [this issue report](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#395)):

> ... Such functions are called conversion functions. No return type can be specified.

That rule is what makes implementations forbid `* operator int() { }`. You can also argue with 12.4p1, although as that's phrased very general and is the first statement in the destructors section, I think the other statement above should be the primary argument

> A special declarator syntax using an optional function-specifier (7.1.2) followed by ˜ followed by the destructor's class name followed by an empty parameter list is used to declare the destructor in a class definition.

As can be seen/read there is no mention of declarators such as `*` in that description, which shows the intent of the authors.